# Wordpress Navigation remove container

Tags: wordpress, navigation, containers

Hi I have a problem with wordpress navigation tools. What I want to do is remove the containing class.

According to the documentation by setting 'containter' => false removes the containing class.

But the problem is when I have done so, nothing happened.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 
                        'container' => false
                        ) ); ?>
```

But when the menu is displayed it is still enclosed inside a  tag.

Do yo guys have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: try putting false between sigle quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to set Header Menu in the functions.php and in the admin panel as well.

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
    )
);
```

Make sure to use both and that in the admin panel the menus are set to the correct menu container.